# How to display selected item in scrollable horizontal list

Tags: mobile, mobile-application, mobile-first

I have a scrollable horizontal card list.

Only one card can be selected inside the list. How should the selected item be displayed from a good UX perspective?

eg.

1. With a border around the card.
2. Making the selected card slightly large than the other cards.
3. Displaying an icon like a check mark on the selected card

Something else?

Answer (score 1):

You could just set an opacity to all other cards except the candidate one. If you don't like this approach I think all solution could be accepted. It's very dependent on the whole layout so you can't say that the best solution is the 1 or 2 or 3